# How to calculate the size of a non full screen page sheet view on iPad

Tags: swift, width, cgsize

Im trying to calculate the width of this view not the entire screen but i'm getting the whole screen width not the page sheet view on iPad.

On iPhone it is fine because the page sheet covers the whole width. But on iPads its different

```
let width : CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `view.bounds.size.width`

Comment: I tried `view.frame.size.width` and also your proposal but they are the same

Comment: ok let me know if it works

Comment: Where are you calling this statement? In a viewController? If so then self is the viewController and `view` is the viewController's view. Where do you set `view` to point to your intended view?

Comment: @Magnas it is written in the ‘viewDidLoad’ of the viewcontroller. What you see is a view controller displayed as a page sheet not full screen on iOS 13 on an ipad

Comment: Can you show the code for the creation of the child viewController and how you add it to the parent viewController?

Comment: @Magnas i’m not creating any child view controllers. I just segue from one view controller to another but displaying the new view controller as a page sheet not as a full screen. Page sheets are new display methods on ios 13. It is same as ordinary viewcontroller but displayed differently in the view hierarchy. It doesn’t cover the full screen. On iphone it covers only 80% height and leave a space above and on ipads it shows it as you can see in the screen shot. This view controller contains a collection view controller with a page controller to let user slide through the tutorial.

Comment: I’m no using page view controller here for the tutorial or child controller. Will update the code as soon as im back to office to show you the full code. @Magnas